# How to convert jpeg image to dxf format in JAVA?

Tags: java, png, jpeg, dxf

Hi I want to convert images (png, jpeg) to dxf format in my graduation project.

I found that I should use Aspose but it's not free .

please is there any open source java library to do that ?

Comment: I somehow doubt it but you could try to use Image Magick with `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: Converting a raster image to a vector image is pretty hard.  I doubt there are any libraries for doing it.

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion won't work. IM 'converted'  on my test by simply creating another jpg with a dxf extension. Naughty ;)

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is usually off-topic for SO. Instead you could ask at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). 
That said, I don't understand why you would want to convert raster images to a CAD/3D/vector format.